# Phoenix and Ecto and SELECTs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an association set up in Ecto models in Phoenix. An Organization has many OrganizationMembers. In the OrganizationMember controller's Edit method, I'm trying to create a SELECT element that will hold all of the Organizations to choose from. In the *edit* definitiion, I've got the following two lines:

```
# organizations = Enum.to_list(from(o in Organization, order_by: o.name, select: [o.name, o.id]))
organizations = from(o in Organization, order_by: o.name, select: {o.name, o.id})
```

This is my line in the template to show the select:

```
<%= select f, :organization_id, @organizations, prompt: "Choose your organization" %>
```

If I keep the first line commented, I get this error on the template select:

> protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Query

If I use the first line and comment the second one, I get this error in the controller:

> protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Query

How do I get the select to properly show the select dropdown and the values? BTW the organization_id comes from this:

```
organization_member = Repo.get!(OrganizationMember, id) |> Repo.preload(:organization)    
organization_id = organization_member.organization.id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error messages say, an `%Ecto.Query{}` is not an Enumerable. If you want to bring the query results, you must call the repository and give it the query:

```
Repo.all from(o in Organization, order_by: o.name, select: {o.name, o.id})
```

PS: Note I changed the valued returned by select into a tuple because that's what the form `select` needs.

Comment: I'm coming from a c# background and I think I'm getting tripped up by the LINQ-like syntax. I didn't realize that the _from_ just returns a query and not an actual data set.