# Why I get protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Query?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Although I am passing the query to repository inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576899/phoenix-and-ecto-and-selects) like this:

```
teams_users = Repo.all (from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id))
    |> Enum.each( &team_users/1 )


def team_users (team) do
    %{id: id} = team
    Repo.all (from(tu in TeamUser, where: tu.team_id == ^id))
end
```

However, I got this error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.450.0> terminating
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Query<from t in App.Team, where: t.owner_id == ^1>
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:116: Enumerable.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1477: Enum.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:609: Enum.each/2
    (App) web/channels/user_channel.ex:93: App.UserChannel.handle_in/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:223: Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:681: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the teams, then get the users of each team, then I expect to have all the users in one array.

Do I miss something? any advice? is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you have an issue here with this code:

```
teams_users = Repo.all (from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id))
|> Enum.each( &team_users/1 )
```

You should remove the space between `Repo.all` and `(`

```
teams_users = Repo.all(from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id))
|> Enum.each( &team_users/1 )
```

You could also write this as:

```
teams_users =
from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id)
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.each( &team_users/1 )
```

However, doing this introduces an n + 1 query. You will make one query to fetch your teams, then another to fetch the team users. You should look into [Repo.preload/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/2) for this.

```
teams_users =
  from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id)
  |> Repo.all()
  |> Repo.preload(:team_users)
```

Comment: But, how would I define the association :team_users in schema Team? I am using ecto 3.0-rc, and I already have a many to many table, but I didn't add any associations in my Team, User schemas..

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3 and https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3 should help you out.

Comment: I can't add `belongs_to` to User as it has no `table_id`, I am using another table `team_user` to link Team and User which has `user_id, team_id` how would I define the many to many association?

Comment: There is an example of a has many through association in the docs I linked.

Comment: If you are using Ecto 2 then check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529720/elixir-ecto-2-create-many-to-many-association

Comment: Thanks, I will try to go with has many through, I am using Ecto 3

Answer (score 2):

You are piping a query macro directly into Enum.each, instead of resolving the query with Repo.all and sending it into Enum.